# How to convert xlsx file to .mdf extension

Tags: sql, sql-server, file

i have data stored in xlsx file with one column of image.

how can i transfer my data from xlsx file to mdf database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can convert it, but you can certainly import the `xlsx` file into a `table` within a SQL Server database.

[How to import data from Excel to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)